# Adding a drag and drop re-ordering from a custom post type default list

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, hooks

I have custom post type named '**slider_to_be_ordered**' and has the following arguments enabled:

```
 'supports'              => array( 'title', 'page-attributes' ),
 'hierarchical'          => true,
```

and I have the following default view:

[image: custom post type that needs to be ordered by drag and dropping its order]

I've seen there are plugins that enables that feature but would like to implement it using the WP-packaged jquery UI sortable but I would like to check first if there any hooks/filters/args that can be used to enable the drag and drop re-ordering, similar to the default menu re-ordering?

If the code implementation is complex, any clues on how to use jquery UI sortable to achieve the drag-and-drop effect?

Comment: I wanted to know this too, so I looked at the code of the ~10 or so plug-ins that have drag and drop post orders. Every one of them its fairly extensive - none of them use any hooks or filters, so the answer is most likely no, it has to be built from scratch. (dissect a post order plugin's code to see how they do it)

Comment: Just look at the jQuery UI docs for this feature.

Comment: hi @kaiser, can I request to re-open this question? it seems I have some code snippets to share to enable drag and drop reordering. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlAlberto Can you not answer it at the moment?